# what is the best way to export content in excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, angular, npm

I have a report data which comes from back end service (.NET) and report format in HTML table.(angular) 
I need to export this report to excel with Angular front end. 
what would be the best way to achieve this? 
 I found couple of ways which would be the better one or suggest if you find any other way

 1. export the html table with xlsx package available on npm.
 2. send http request which will get all the data from back end service including html.

Please also let me know what would the ideal solution for handling export to excel functionality. Is there any documentation Microsoft provides?

Answer (score 1):

I use EPPlus on the back end in ASP.NET to generate Excel files. Open source,  works great, far easier to deal with than manually creating the XLSX packages, and it supports a number advanced Excel features.